# Laravel 4.2 Not Returning View::make

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, mariadb

Okay so Laravel 4.2; MariaDB; ect

Trying to query a sql string "test", i know it's there since i created it.

Here's my SearchController.php code:

```
 // Here search is ok.
        $start = microtime(true);
        $items = Project::processSearch('+' . implode(' +', $searchTerms), false, $this->limitPerPage, $page, $this->maxSearchResults);
        $executionTime = microtime(true) - $start;
        $total = $items->getTotal();

        if($total == 0)
        {
            $start = microtime(true);
            $items = Project::processSearch(implode(' ', $searchTerms),
                true, $this->limitPerPage, $page, $this->limitPerPage);
            $executionTime = microtime(true) - $start;

            $total = $items->getTotal();

            if($total > 0)
            {
                return View::make('search.results')
                    ->with('items', $items)
                    ->with('executionTime', number_format($executionTime, 4))
                    ->with('info', "Your query didn't return any result.");
            }
        }
```

here's my class code

```
public static function processSearch($query, $suggestions, $resultsPerPage, $page, $limit = null)
{
    $slug = Str::slug($query) . '-general';
    $slug .= $suggestions ? '-suggestions' : '-exact-search';

    $results = Cache::remember($slug, 10, function() use($query, $limit)
    {
        $items = Project::whereRaw(
            "MATCH(mixed) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)",
            array($query)
        )->take(301);

        if(Auth::check())
        {
            $items = $items->with(['unlockedItemsUser' => function($query)
            {
                $query->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
            }]);
        }

        if($limit != null)
        {
            $items = $items->limit($limit);
        }

        $items = $items->get();

        if(count($items) > 0 && is_object($items))
        {
            return $items->all();
        }

        return null;
    });

    if($results != null)
    {
        $pages = objectlist_chunk($results, $resultsPerPage);
        return Paginator::make($pages[$page - 1], count($results), $resultsPerPage);
    }

    return Paginator::make(array(), 0, $resultsPerPage);
}



public function unlockedItemsUser()
{
    return $this->hasMany('UnlockedItem', 'item_id', 'id');
}

public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = false)
{
    $query = parent::newQuery();
    if($excludeDeleted)
    {
        $query->where('deleted', '=', '0');
    }
    $query->where('blacklist', '=', 0);

    return $query;
}
```

}

Here's my routes

```
Route::controller('getIndex', 'SearchController');
Route::controller('/search', 'SearchController');
Route::resource('getIndex', 'SearchController');
Route::controller('/user', 'UserController');
Route::controller('/maintenance', 'MaintenanceController');
```

I created the string "test" In mysql inside the correct table and database; everything is fine. But when i try to query "test" it returns with "No results found"; even tho i clearly see it.

Idk if this helps; but here's a profiler section i found interesting: 
[image]

thank you in advanced!

Comment: You don't return any view if no results were found, maybe that is the problem

Comment: Yeah, but there should be a result. Which is "test". Am i missing something? Sorry im very exhausted been up for a 2 days. going to go knock out. will pm you in the am!

Comment: If this is a MySQL question, please provide the _generated_ SQL statement(s) and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning any view if your first call to `processSearch` give you value.

```
$start = microtime(true);
$items = Project::processSearch('+' . implode(' +', $searchTerms), false, $this->limitPerPage, $page, $this->maxSearchResults);
$executionTime = microtime(true) - $start;
$total = $items->getTotal();

if($total == 0)
{
    $start = microtime(true);
    $items = Project::processSearch(implode(' ', $searchTerms),
        true, $this->limitPerPage, $page, $this->limitPerPage);
    $executionTime = microtime(true) - $start;

    $total = $items->getTotal();

    if($total > 0)
    {
        return View::make('search.results')
            ->with('items', $items)
            ->with('executionTime', number_format($executionTime, 4))
            ->with('info', "Your query didn't return any result.");
    } else {

        return View::make('search.results')
            ->with('items', $items)
            ->with('executionTime', number_format($executionTime, 4))
            ->with('info', 'There is nothing to show');
    }
}

return View::make('search.results')
            ->with('items', $items)
            ->with('executionTime', number_format($executionTime, 4));
```